# SQL - get records from many-to-many relations by the user itself -OR- his group

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two database tables, one as the main table and the other as the relation table.
The first table is a table of contents and the second table is a table that connects to users or groups.
Some data may also be modified in this second table.

I'm not sure about the structure and performance.

for example, we have User Id 160 which is under group id 7

So for the first, we have a `post` Table.

```
id  |  title  |  content    |   cover  | status
------------------------------------------------
1   | first   |  content 1  | /img/... |   1
2   | second  |  content 2  | /img/... |   1
3   | another |  content 3  | /img/... |   1
4   | four    |  content 4  | /img/... |   1
5   | five    |  content 5  | /img/... |   1
```

and for the second we have a `post_rel` Table:

```
id  | group_id | user_id | post_id |  title   |   cover  | sort | status
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   | 7        | NULL    | 1       | g title  | img/...  | 1    | 1
2   | NULL     | 160     | 1       | u title  | NULL     | 2    | 1     ***  selected for user_id
3   | 7        | NULL    | 2       | NULL     | img/...  | 6    | 0
4   | NULL     | 160     | 2       | NULL     | img/...  | 4    | 1     ***  selected for user_id
5   | NULL     | 160     | 3       | some     | img/...  | 3    | 1     ***  selected for user_id
6   | 7        | NULL    | 4       | NULL     | img/...  | 9    | 1     ***  selected for group_id
7   | NULL     | 165     | 5       | NULL     | img/...  | 5    | 0
```

This is the basic query we have.

```
select 
    `post_rel`.`title` as `custom_title`, 
    `post_rel`.`cover` as `custom_cover`, 
    `post_rel`.`group_id`, 
    `post_rel`.`user_id`, 
    `post`.* 
from 
    `post` 
        inner join `post_rel` on `post`.`id` = `post_rel`.`post_id` 
        where 
            `post`.`status` = 1 
            and `post_rel`.`status` = 1 
            and ( 
                `post_rel`.`user_id` = 160 
                or ( 
                    `post_rel`.`group_id` = 7 
                    and `post_rel`.`post_id` not in (
                            select 
                                `post_rel`.`post_id` 
                            from 
                                `post_rel` 
                            where 
                                `post_rel`.`user_id` = 160
                    )
                )
            )
order by 
    `post_rel`.`sort` asc
```

So, what you think about the basic query? Especially in the subquery, won't performance drop in a large table? Is it possible to write a better and simpler query or change the structure?

Edit: this is sqlfiddle example of my code and structure http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed9d4b/1

Comment: Please, describe the logic you need to have

Comment: @astentx What you mean about logic? I want to put users in different groups if they link to the content or change it or deactivate the content to be displayed according to their opinion. But if they do nothing, the output will be displayed based on the values I set for the group.

Comment: `OR` conditions are not generally optimized well by MySQL. It's usually better to split it into two queries and combine them with `UNION`.

Comment: @Ali.Sh Okay, you need to show the title and the cover as per user preferences if it was set, and as per group setting if it was not set for user. Am I right? What should be the output if there are multiple groups per user per post? All in all, we need a sample input and sample output you want to get.

Comment: @Strawberry I added sqlfiddle example

Comment: @astentx, Yes, but actually we make each user just in one group so it's unique for every user. also I added sqlfiddle with structure and data and basic query example for better understood.

Comment: @Barmar, I try to use union, but can't figure it out. can you please more specified based on my basic query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change it to use "not exists" instead of "not in" and would use aliases so I could pull it off like so:

```
select 
    b.`title` as `custom_title`, 
    b.`cover` as `custom_cover`, 
    b.`group_id`, 
    b.`user_id`, 
    a.* 
from 
    `post` a
        inner join `post_rel` b on a.`id` = b.`post_id` 
        where 
            a.`status` = 1 
            and b.`status` = 1 
            and ( 
                b.`user_id` = 160 
                or ( 
                    b.`group_id` = 7 
                    and not exists (
                            select 
                                'x' 
                            from 
                                `post_rel` c
                            where 
                                c.`user_id` = 160 and c.`post_id`=b.`post_id`
                    )
                )
            )
order by 
    b.`sort` asc
```

Typically when managing users and group, there's this notion of an exception user who directly can get assigned to assets just like the whole group. This seems to be an example of that.

From a modeling-only perspective, there are 2 ways to deal with that:

1. Ensure that every user exists in a group and that you only assign assets to groups. For the exception user, create a group. You could even enforce that every user belongs to only one group. This way your post_rel table deals with only groups. Unfortunately, the relationship between group and user is not understood well enough to weigh in appropriately.
2. Driven only by the need to eliminate null values towards a good model which also reduces overhead, the other option is to use name value pairs and allows the User and Group to exist in the same field with another field besides it, denoting Group or User.
   These are the SQL Fiddle:

NOT EXISTS version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1af8cf/2

NOT IN version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1af8cf/1

Some reading on nulls https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-size.html

Specifically:

> Declare columns to be NOT NULL if possible. It makes SQL operations faster, by enabling better use of indexes and eliminating overhead for testing whether each value is NULL. You also save some storage space, one bit per column. If you really need NULL values in your tables, use them. Just avoid the default setting that allows NULL values in every column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It doesn't seem to make much difference, (I tested it with a million fake records). Does it have a special advantage?

Comment: Functionally yes - Not INs do not work with NULLs in the subquery while NOT EXISTS does. IN is usually reserved for small lists and works better than EXISTS in those scenarios.
Depending on the database engine, there might be more logical reads for one versus the other usually favoring NOT EXISTS as data gets very large. I think you would need to get way beyond 1MM transactions (like in an Enterprise application) to start seeing issues.
I have always erred on the side of caution by using NOT EXISTS instead of NOT IN for correctness alone and better performance sometimes.

Comment: The other thing of course is the design for the post_rel table. If you could share the intent, a befitting model could be devised. Right now, it looks like a bad model with null values everywhere. For example, why are users null when group is not null and vice-versa. Are users part of a group? What is the group title/ user title used for and how does it relate to the rest of the data? Was this some quick and dirty way to assign users sometimes and groups sometimes to assets?

Comment: Thanks for the helpful details. (I put sqlfiddle in the first post if can more help for structure)

Group title or User title is just optional.
In fact, I'm trying to make every user sync with the whole group when they don't have any custom record in post_rel. so the Group manager makes changes and all users get exact data. but if some users make changes their data would be displayed.

so first we have a system with a default post table. and second group manager with custom group data in post_rel and finally we have user's custom data.

Comment: I'm not trying to make quick and dirty way. actually, I'm just trying to make the best way. 

maybe I should make 3 tables. 
post, post_cusom, post_relation but maybe we have extra joined here.

or I should create morph fields in post_rel. for example owner_type, owner_id (group/user + id)

I don't know which way is the better way. do you think I can make a better model? do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No worries. Just trying to understand. It's a common scenario and folks deal with it differently as I show in my answer. Anyway, good luck with everything. You have the bigger picture so you'll know what's best.